# Delete all rows if input parameter is 0 otherwise delete only those entries which match the input param

Tags: sql-server, join, delete, batch-processing

I have a stored proc which is receiving id as input. If the id which is received is 0 then we need to delete all the rows otherwise we need to delete only those rows which matches the input id.

I can do this by splitting my query using an if-else but that's the catch here, we want to do it in a single query by using `JOINS` and `CASE` (may be).

Here is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE InfineonFiles (
    infimax INTEGER NOT NULL,
    neonId  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    eTime   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    pTime   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cisId   INTEGER NOT NULL )
```

Input attribute is say,

```
DECLARE @inpId INT = [ 0 OR POSITIVE INTEGER]
```

Deletion is like this

```
IF @inpId = 0
    DELETE TOP (5000) AIA FROM InfineonFiles WHERE pTime < @timeUnitInSeconds 
ELSE
    DELETE TOP (5000) AIA FROM InfineonFiles WHERE pTime < @timeUnitInSeconds AND cisId = inpId
```

The above needs to be in a single query. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below should work in a single query, assuming that cisId is positive only.

```
DELETE TOP (5000) AIA 
FROM InfineonFiles  
WHERE pTime < @timeUnitInSeconds 
AND ( cisId = @inpId OR @inpId =0)
```

... but to be honest I do not really understand what could be a reason not to split that and I would leave your query as it is originally.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did using the `CASE` statement. Can someonehelp me with the performance difference between this and the `OR` approach.

```
DELETE TOP (5000) IFF
FROM InfineonFiles IFF
WHERE ( IFF.cisId = CASE @inpId
       WHEN 0 THEN IFF.cisID
       ELSE @inpId END)
```

Comment: Using `CASE` in a `WHERE` clause *can* overly complicate the predicate for.the SQL Engine causing it to perform poorly. You're probably better off using Radek's solution, but obviously do your due diligence testing both. Also, you forgot this predicate in your answer: `WHERE pTime < @timeUnitInSeconds`.